How do I create a Mapbox tileset from multiple GeoTIFFs
I have 22GB of aerial photography that I'd like to display on a map. The data is a collection of GeoTIFFs, where each image is only 15MB.
From looking at the mapbox uploads API, I can't see a way to create a tileset from more than one file. Is it even possible?
